# why does the valign option not seem to work?

Tags: html, html-table, vertical-alignment

I have a page with a table within which I would like to make use of the `valign` option but it doesn't seem to work. The link is: http://www.quaaoutlodge.com/content/awards and there's a table with three columns, the left and the right column, both have the td tags set to `valign="top"` but the content still centers and does not align on top, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already set

```
media="all"
table, th, td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

in your reset.css file. It is over riding your valign="top" code. You need something like below

```
<td class="rtecenter" style="
vertical-align: top;">
  --------------------
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

your `reset.css` line no 55 remove this css

```
table, th, td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`valign` is no longer a supported tag and you should use the `vertical-align` CSS elements instead.

```
<td style="vertical-align:top;"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the in tag attribute doesn't work, but if you add a CSS class with the following definition it will work.

```
<td class="vaClass">...</td>

.vaClass {
   vertical-align: top; 
}
```